# web component composition not always correctly rendered in Chrome

Tags: javascript, web-component

I am using a composition of web components which is correctly rendered in firefox and safari but not in chrome. Indeed, sometimes the nested components are not displayed in this browser and I cannot figure out why and how to solve the problem.

here is the code:

`index.html` fetches data from a json file and displays the 2 components accordingly.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="module" src="/rect-shape.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/shape-container.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>rect-shape:</p>
    <script>
        const innerEl = document.createElement('rect-shape');
        document.body.appendChild(innerEl);
        fetch('./shapes.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(object => innerEl.color = object.shapes[0].color);
    </script>
    <hr>
    <p>shape-container:</p>
    <script>
        const outerEl = document.createElement('shape-container');
        document.body.appendChild(outerEl);
        fetch('./shapes.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(object => outerEl.shapes = object.shapes);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`shapes.json`: allows parameterizing the shapes from an external service

```json
{
    "shapes": [
        {
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "color": "blue"
        }
    ]
}
```

`shape-container.js`:

```js
import '/rect-shape.js';
(function() {
    const template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
        rect-shape {
            display: inline-table;
        }
    </style>
    `;
    class ShapeContainer extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
            this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        }
        set shapes(data) {
            try {
                this.shapeArray = data;
                this.renderShapes();
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
        renderShapes() {
            this.shapeArray.forEach(shape => {
                const innerElement = document.createElement('rect-shape');
                this.shadowRoot.appendChild(innerElement);
                innerElement.color = shape.color;
            });
        }
    }
    customElements.define('shape-container', ShapeContainer);
}());
```

`rect-shape.js`:

```js
(function() {
    const template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
        svg {
            height: 100;
        }
    </style>
    <div>
        <svg id="port-view" viewbox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" />
        </svg>
    </div>
    `;
    class RectShape extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
            this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        }
        set color(value) {
            if (value) {
                this.setAttribute("color", value);
            } else {
            this.removeAttribute("color");
            }
        }
        get color() {
            return this.getAttribute("color");
        }
        static get observedAttributes() {
            return ["color"];
        }
        attributeChangedCallback(name) {
            switch(name) {
                case "color":
                    this.colorizeRect();
                    break;
            }
        }
        colorizeRect() {
           this.shadowRoot.querySelector('rect')
           .style.setProperty('fill', this.color);
        }
    }
    customElements.define('rect-shape', RectShape);
}());
```

expected rendering:
[image: expected rendering]

rendering with chrome (sometimes):
[image: chrome rendering]

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned the code, keeping your functionality, where is Chrome going wrong?

```js
class BaseElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
           .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}
customElements.define('rect-shape', class extends BaseElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["color"];
  }
  set color( value ) {
    this.setAttribute("color", value);
  }
  attributeChangedCallback( name, oldValue, newValue ) {
    if (name == "color") this.shadowRoot
                             .querySelector('rect')
                             .style
                             .setProperty('fill', newValue);
  }
});
customElements.define('shape-container', class extends BaseElement {
  set shapes( data ) {
    data.forEach( shape => {
      this.shadowRoot
          .appendChild(document.createElement('rect-shape'))
          .color = shape.color;
    });
  }
});
let shapeArray = {
    "shapes": [{ "color": "red" }, { "color": "yellow" }, { "color": "blue" } ]
  }
$Rect.color = 'rebeccapurple';
$Container.shapes = shapeArray.shapes;
```

```html
<template id="RECT-SHAPE">
    <style> svg { width: 70px }</style>
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" />
    </svg>
</template>

<template id="SHAPE-CONTAINER">
  <style> rect-shape { display: inline-table }</style>
</template>

rect-shape:
<br><rect-shape id=$Rect></rect-shape>

<br>shape-container:
<br><shape-container id=$Container></shape-container>
```

Comment: Hello Danny, Thanks for the cleanup. I did not mentioned it but the end application fetches the shapes.json file from an external service. Does your cleanup is also representative of this functionality when using the let declaration?

Comment: Yes, Wrap those 2 setters in a setTimeout and you simulate a fetch delay; that doesn't make any difference